# Problem with FSMC SRAM interface with STM32F207ZG

Tags: stm32

I have been struggling for 3 days now to get this interface working and write to SRAM properly , but this is not working still , Here is the code i used.

```
int main(void)
{
  SRAM_Init();
  while (1) {
    *(uint16_t *) (0x64000000)=0xAADD; // break point here
  }
}
//
//
//

void SRAM_Init(void)
{
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitTypeDef  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure;
  FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitTypeDef  p;
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

  /* Enable GPIOs clock */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD | RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE
    |RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOF| RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOG, ENABLE);

  /* Enable FSMC clock */
  RCC_AHB3PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB3Periph_FSMC, ENABLE);

  /* GPIOD configuration */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource0, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource1, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_FSMC);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_4 | 
    GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 |
    GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;

  GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* GPIOE configuration */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource0 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource1 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource7 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource8 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource9 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource10 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource11 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource12 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource13 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource14 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource15 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0  | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_7 |
                  GPIO_Pin_8  | GPIO_Pin_9  | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11|
                  GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;

  GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* GPIOF configuration */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource0 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource1 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource2 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource3 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource4 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource5 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource12 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource13 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource14 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOF, GPIO_PinSource15 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0  | GPIO_Pin_1  | GPIO_Pin_2  |
                                 GPIO_Pin_3 | GPIO_Pin_4  | GPIO_Pin_5  |
                                GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | 
                                GPIO_Pin_15;      

  GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* GPIOG configuration */
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource0 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource1 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource2 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource3 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource4 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource5 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOG, GPIO_PinSource9 , GPIO_AF_FSMC);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0  | GPIO_Pin_1  | GPIO_Pin_2  |
                                 GPIO_Pin_3 |
                                GPIO_Pin_4  | GPIO_Pin_5  |GPIO_Pin_9;      

  GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /*-- FSMC Configuration ------------------------------------------------------*/
  p.FSMC_AddressSetupTime = 5;
  p.FSMC_AddressHoldTime = 0;
  p.FSMC_DataSetupTime = 5;
  p.FSMC_BusTurnAroundDuration = 0;
  p.FSMC_CLKDivision = 0;
  p.FSMC_DataLatency = 0;
  p.FSMC_AccessMode = FSMC_AccessMode_A;

  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_Bank = FSMC_Bank1_NORSRAM2;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_DataAddressMux = FSMC_DataAddressMux_Disable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_MemoryType = FSMC_MemoryType_SRAM;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_MemoryDataWidth = FSMC_MemoryDataWidth_16b;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_BurstAccessMode = FSMC_BurstAccessMode_Disable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignalPolarity = FSMC_WaitSignalPolarity_Low;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WrapMode = FSMC_WrapMode_Disable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignalActive = FSMC_WaitSignalActive_BeforeWaitState;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteOperation = FSMC_WriteOperation_Enable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignal = FSMC_WaitSignal_Disable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_ExtendedMode = FSMC_ExtendedMode_Disable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteBurst = FSMC_WriteBurst_Disable;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_ReadWriteTimingStruct = &p;
  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteTimingStruct = &p;

  FSMC_NORSRAMInit(&FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure);

  /*!< Enable FSMC Bank1_SRAM2 Bank */
  FSMC_NORSRAMCmd(FSMC_Bank1_NORSRAM2, ENABLE);
}

//

//
```

Now when i debug , i see that many addresses change , and never get the write value in place.

My SRAM chip and MCU are the same as the ones on that board but separate , so definitly they are supposed to work together.

http://www.hotmcu.com/hystm32f2xxcore144-coredev-board-p-3.html?cPath=1_20

Comment: You may need test equipment to debug this, unless you can recognize a problem by inspection.  You might use a dual trace or external trigger scope to see if you ever actuate the write signals to the RAM. Then if that works examine data and address lines one by one, etc.  A logic analyzer, if available, can help too.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same kit, thanks for your code!  I searched for a long time to interface the SRAM and this was exactly what I wanted.

I have the STM32F4 with the assert function implemented, I have found the bug in your code with that :

```
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 


  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */

clCOM3.Print((char*)file);
clCOM3.PrintUNum(line,0);

  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

You need just one more line of code to make it work correctly:

```
FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_AsynchronousWait = FSMC_AsynchronousWait_Disable;
```

Comment: It would help if you said **where** to add this line of code.

Comment: Just before ram initialization with the structure :

FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_AsynchronousWait = FSMC_AsynchronousWait_Disable;

 FSMC_NORSRAMInit(&FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure);